# How do I restrict a Java application from closing?

Tags: java, security, authentication

I have a security based application in Java, and I want that application not to be closed or minimized by the user while running.

Comment: It sounds as if you want an application that takes over the computer, disabling task-switching so that the user has no choice but to do only whatever that application allows him to do.  If I knew an application had such behavior, I would not ever put it on my machine.  It sounds like a nasty piece of malware, not to mention poor software engineering.  I can't even think of a piece of Microsoft software that treats me that badly.

Comment: I hope very much that you do not find a solution, for the very same reasons @rcook mentioned. To which I add: it could be the case that services on the internet help save human lives under unforeseeable circumstances. How would you feel if you learned that someone died because your users couldn't exit your app and fire up a browser?

Answer (score 2):

What you are wanting to do is impossible. Modern operating systems are designed so that what you want to do is not possible. It would be a security threat if it was.

Even if you managed to lock out the keyboard and mouse, they would still be able to login to the machine remotely (assuming it is set up of course) and kill of anything they wanted.

If they do not have remote access setup. There is nothing stopping them from switching the computer off - by force if necessary and restarting.

I would look at options of what you can do if they close or minimise the application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any available restrictions, but perhaps you could override the use of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>,... So your users can't exit your application through tabbing.